# Issue with Margin in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have created *PDF* report using *iReport*. *PDF* output is looking fine, but when I click on print, In Hardcopy (paper) too much empty space at left, right and bottom places. The font size automatically decreased because of this.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: You should add the screenshot of your report's design (in *iReport*) and the screenshot of the resulting report

Comment: <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="rc" pageWidth="800" pageHeight="2000" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">

Comment: It is not a screenshot. And it is better to edit the question, not to add a comment

Answer (score 0):

Your page width is set to 800, but your column width is 535. If you only have one column, increase the column width to 760 (800 - 20 right margin - 20 left margin).

Your page height is set to 2,000 and is probably responsible for the extra space at the bottom. Decrease that as desired.

Comment: All my components(sublist,text and lables) arranged..it's taking 2000 height, i'm not able to decrease...

Comment: So there is no extra space at the bottom?

Comment: Post your JRXML and a screenshot of your report so we can take a look at them.

Comment: Please verify...https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nRDG3XlHJFoJSMVvllT3N5SVi53cdRLU8h3d9IBKWEY/edit

Comment: How much extra space is at the bottom? I think you should have maybe 150-180 pixels of space depending on the page. The page size is:
     1150
     - 20 top margin
     - 50 title band
     - 851 group header
     - 30 page footer
     - 20 bottom margin

Or
     1150
     - 20 top margin
     - 930 detail band
     - 30 page footer
     - 20 bottom margin

So if 150 - 180 pixels of extra space at the bottom sounds like what you're seeing, you might want to decrease the overall page height from 1150 to maybe 1000.

Comment: I have decreased page size to 1000. but problem not been solved

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jasper Report plugins in Eclipse IDE then

1. Just right click on the (Design) page of Jasper Report and select 'Page 
   Format' option.
2. You will see 'Page Format' window.
3. Now make changes as you want.